# Unusual ways to kill people with air manipulation

Tags: internal-consistency, magic

Apart from suffocating them or blowing them away, how could you kill someone by manipulating only air? Assume they are on a plain devoid of any objects. Also assume that you CAN'T manipulate air on the molecular level.

he can move air molecules around as a large group
he cannot manipulate individual air molecules
he also was limited to what he can see or feel
he does have a sort of air sense)
he cannot see your body on a cellular level
he won't be able to manipulate Your cells
The wind he is able to produce by a manipulation cannot be any more powerful then want you would see in a very very bad hurricane

Distance:everything with in basic human sense range.

Comment: How much air manipulation are we talking about?

Comment: It looks like you're wanting us to do your brainstorming for you.

Comment: Agreed, the question seems quite broad. For example answers can range from creating a low and high pressure zone that squishes the target to violently ripping all the O2 out of somebodies cells and have a few trillion cells explode simultaneously.

Comment: Down-voted for being over-broad and "except for all of the obvious ways".

Comment: Chasing users to other questions and down-voting them is pretty tacky.

Comment: @BryanMcClure Be nice.

Comment: @RonJon alright fair enough I fixed it now you have two more up vote. Sorry this hasn't been a good day for me.

Comment: You definitely should clarify border conditions for the power of manipulating air. So far there are no reasons to ask the question, the answer can be any type of death. Open criminal records and horror movies - anything you can see there and a lot more. Vote too broad.

Comment: @MolbOrg I added more information is this enough

Comment: still any. try to figure out energy constraints. So far he can blow things in million pieces, launch air carriers to the moon, burn things alive, penetrate them, cut, peel etc. Anything.

Comment: Does the new edits help?

Comment: If it is about that he can manipulate air in form of wind, then yes, it makes it better. Add scale or distance - which volumes we talking about. And the precision of the control maybe - a hurricane-like energy could probably manipulate each brick as floating individual pieced from a big building. A lot of things could be done that way. two spaces at the end of string and enter make everything better or two enters.

Comment: Without using the anatomical weakness of your target there is basically only manipulating over things, wind pressure and wind vibrations.Then all the sub-categories that come under them, If you want to torture you could create sounds, though how specific and ghastly is up to you.

Comment: Not really a full answer but--there have been experiments done regarding wind force and the human body: https://what-if.xkcd.com/66/

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be really nasty, force an air bubble into your opponent's bloodstream and you can cause all kinds of horrific effects; this is why medical professionals always overfill syringes and then push some of the liquid out, because they need to make sure there is no air being injected.

Get an air bubble into the brain and block an artery there, and you give them an instant stroke. Putting a few bubbles into the veins leading to the heart and cutting off blood flow to any part of that is an automatic [heart attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myocardial_infarction). Obstructing blood flow like this in general is basically the definition of an [embolism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embolism), which can easily be fatal; see the link for details on other potential health effects.

Comment: Take a page from the Red mist strategy and collapse a cavity in their bloodstream, producing a hydraulic hammer in their body.

Comment: You could basically give them [the bends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompression_sickness)

Answer (score 4):

### You can get Creative

**Burn them** by super compressing the air around them which can cause a huge spike in temperature. It's the same principle that a [fire piston](http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2010-03/how-start-fire-just-compressed-air) uses.

**Turn them into Red Mist** by creating a cavity in the air then releasing it. The atmosphere will rush back into place at the speed of sound creating a local shockwave. This is similar to how a [Depth Charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_charge) works.

**Focused Shockwaves** consisting of a slug of air moving at multiples of the local Mach number would be deadly. Note: This is not a gust of wind or a shockwave that an explosion could produce.

**Air Jet Cutter**, like a [Water Jet Cutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_jet_cutter) use a filament-thin stream of high-pressure air to slice through your targets, add dust and sand for good measure. Ice crystals formed by the rapidly expanding (cooling air) could work as an abrasive too. The air in the stream would have so much energy in it that it would blast through you.

**Electrocution** by rubbing together to opposing streams of air and building up a massive static charge, not unlike lightning.

Comment: Focused Shockwaves and Air Jet Cutter can be boiled down to the forbidden "blowing them away".  All great answers, though.

Comment: I disagree, neither would be like the wind. The air jet cutter will slice through you because of its energy. The focused shockwave would make the air act if it was a solid object.

Comment: @RonJohn I've added some clarifications

Comment: @RonJohn Well it would be more blowing pieces of them away. Seriously though, pressure and vibrations are really dangerous :D

Comment: I don't think it is blowing them away; either, that sound more like a tornado picking up their whole body. IRL a friend of mine cuts 2-inch steel for ships and bridges with a fine grit (could be sand) cutter like this, it makes hair-thin cuts. Air could blow sand up in the air, refine it to just very fine particles, then hurl a paper thin sheet of it and behead the person, or slice them in half like a super sword. 99.99999% of their body falls to the ground, the rest is nearby: they were no more 'blown away' than if a sword did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

- Kick up a sand storm and bury your enemy.
- Use wind to blow boulders over them.
- If your enemy is on the water, swamp their boats.
- Moses and the Red Sea comes to mind.

Your question just doesn't give enough detail, though.